# Do I need test method that is inside the test class

Tags: java, testing, methods, junit

So I have a sample method that I give him a day and it returns me the first and last day of a week in which the day:

```
public static final DatePeriod thisWeek(LocalDate date) {

    TemporalField dayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(Locale.FRANCE).dayOfWeek();
    LocalDate mon = date.with(dayOfWeek, 1);
    LocalDate sun = date.with(dayOfWeek, 7);

    return new DatePeriod(mon, sun);
}
```

I have to write a JUnit test (and I did it):

```
@Test
public void testThisMonth_LocalDate() throws ParseException {
    System.out.println("thisMonth");
    for (String[] date : VALID_TEST_DATES) {
        LocalDate dateLocal = dateToLocal(date[0]);
        DatePeriod expResult = new DatePeriod(dateToLocal(date[5]), dateToLocal(date[6]));
        DatePeriod result = JavaTimeUtils.thisMonth(dateLocal);
        assertEquals(expResult.getLeft(), result.getLeft());
        assertEquals(expResult.getRight(), result.getRight());
    }
}
```

So, because I used code in **dateToLocal()** multiple times, I decided to make it in method like this:

```
public LocalDate dateToLocal(String dateString) throws ParseException {   // Calendar to LocalDate
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date initDate = df.parse(dateString);
    cal.setTime(initDate);
    LocalDate dateLocal = LocalDate.of(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), Month.of(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    return dateLocal;
}
```

And it works. 
But that is not my question.
I was wondering is this the *correct way* to do things like this (method in this JUnit test), do I need to make Test for this method, do I have to move it in other class (outside the tests)? I know this is strange question, I've already searching in google, unsuccessfully. (maybe I can't  ask google right).
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no absolute way to do something, and everything depends on the project.

This topic is open to everybody's subjectivity.

IMO, if you use a block of code multiple times in a single test class, that block should be extracted in a local method.

If you use it in multiple test methods, you should look into inheritance or creating a small util class under test packages.

If the method is also needed in your main java code, it's then that you should write unit tests for it. The purpose of tests is to validate you **runtime** code. JUnit code is run pre-runtime.

Comment: I'm grateful for all responses, but your was the exact I was searching for.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to test the test method (as others have pointed out). However, I would recommend storing the expected results as LocalDate instances rather than creating them on the fly from strings. That way you are safe from possible bugs in the conversion code.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't a good idea to write "test for test". I worked in many companies and nowhere we did it. There is enough of what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally acceptable to have helper methods in test classes. In fact, when testing things of any large complexity it's hard not to. Unless the test helper method is in a utility class used across multiple tests in multiple projects (and thus being in the main jar of a different project) I don't typically consider it useful to write tests for the test helper methods (otherwise, taken to the logical conclusion, it'd be nearly impossible to have any code reuse and fully tested classes).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the rules for this are similar the same for test code and production code:

- If you use a code pattern more than once within a class, extract it to a method
- If you use it in more than one class in the same package, move the method to a utility class with package-level visibility
- If you use it in multiple packages, move the utility class to a dedicated utility package, make it public
- If you use the code in more than one project, move it to a team-specific library
- If you find that your entire organization needs this functionality repeatedly, move it to a global library
- If you find that the whole world needs it, open-source it

Basically: Make the code as visible as it needs to be, but not more

And yes, if you extract your code to a utility class (2nd bullet or below), then I'd expect a dedicated test / test suite for the code